# Editar banco de dados MySQL com php

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro em php, e utilizando o mysql como db, já consegui fazer a pagina de cadastro e ela está funcionando normalmente. O problema é que agora preciso de que quando o cadastro seja criado seja gerado um link para editar e que ao clicar nele seja possível editar os dados no banco de dados.

O código que executa o cadastro:

```
 <?php
 /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: Arnaud
  * Date: 22/05/2017
  * Time: 16:38
  */

 $nome = $_POST["txtnome"];
 $email = $_POST["txtemail"];
 $telefone = $_POST["txttelefone"];
 $senha = $_POST["txtpass"];
 $data = $_POST["txtdata"];
 $id = $_POST["id"];

 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysqli_select_db($con,"testeconstrusite");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
     echo "Falha ao conectar ao servidor MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }


 if(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($telefone) && !empty($senha) && !empty($data) && !empty($id) && empty($id)) {
     mysqli_query($con, "insert into clientes (nome_cliente, email_cliente, telefone_cliente, senha_cliente, data_nasc_cliente) VALUE('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$senha', STR_TO_DATE('$data','%d/%m/%Y'))");
     $id_inserido = mysqli_insert_id($con);
     echo "Cliente inserido com id de número: $id_inserido <br>";
     echo "Para editar o usuário cadastrado clique <a href='index.php?id=$id_inserido'>aqui</a>";
 }

 elseif(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($telefone) && !empty($senha) && !empty($data) && !empty($id) && !empty($id)){
     mysqli_query($con, "update clientes set nome_cliente ='$nome', email_cliente='$email', telefone_cliente='$telefone', senha_cliente='$senha', data_nasc_cliente=STR_TO_DATE('$data','%d/%m/%Y') where id_cliente = '$id'");
 }

 else{
     echo "Preencha todos os campos!";
 }
```

A pagina do formulário:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>

     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"  href="estilos/estilo.css" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

     <title>Cadastro</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="formulario" class = formulario>
 <form action="cadastrar.php" method="post">

     <input type='text' name="id" class='campo' id="id" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET["id"])){echo $_GET["id"];}; ?>">

     <label>Nome *</label><br>
     <input type='text' name="txtnome" class='campo' id="txtnome" required>
     <br>

     <label>E-mail *</label><br>
     <input type="email" class='campo' required="required" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
     <br>

     <label>Telefone *<span class="esmaecido"></span> </label><br>
     <script type="text/javascript">$("#txttelefone").mask("(00) 0000-00009");</script>
     <input type="tel" class="campo" name="txttelefone" id="txttelefone" required="required" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\)[\s][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,5}" />
     <br>

     <label>Senha *</label><br>
     <input type="password" name="txtpass" class='campo' required="required" id="txtpass">
     <br>

     <label>Data de Nascimento *</label><br>
     <script type="text/javascript">$("#txtdata").mask('00/00/0000');</script>
     <input type='data' name="txtdata" id="txtdata" class='campo' required="required">
     <br>


     <input type='submit' name='BTEnvia' value='Cadastrar' class = botao><br>

 </form>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: utilize a mesma página, e use um campo hidden para guardar a chave primária. Se a chave for vazia, você insere, caso contrário, update

Comment: Mas como crio um link pra pessoa clicar e a chave primária já ir preenchida? Eu tenho uma pagina html e uma php.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis

Comment: você deve ter uma página inserir cliente correto? Ex. você tem um botão inserir cliente, que abre essa página, faça um editar cliente que também irá abrir essa página, porém passando um valor no POST com a chave que você precisa editar. A partir daí, basta testar se esse valor não é vazio e dar o select no banco, e preencher os campos

Comment: @RovannLinhalis tentei, mas não consigo entender

Comment: tente editar sua pergunta e postar o código das páginas que você tem

Comment: @RovannLinhalis editado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize a mesma página para inserir e editar os registros.

Nesta página coloque um campo para guardar a chave primária do registro selecionado.

No botão salvar, se o campo estiver vazio, realiza o `INSERT`, se estiver preenchido, `UPDATE`.

Na hora de abrir a página a partir de um botão `INSERIR CLIENTE` abra-a normalmente, Na hora de abrir a partir de um botão `EDITAR CLIENTE` abra-a informando um parâmetro, seja por `GET` ou `POST`, que tenha o valor da chave primária do registro que queria editar.

Ao carregar a página, verifique se esse parâmetro é vazio, se sim, abre a tela limpa para o usuário cadastrar um novo cliente, se não, executa a select no banco de dados e preenche os campos com os dados do cliente selecionado.

Segue um exemplo:

**PHP**

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST["txtnome"];
 $email = $_POST["txtemail"];
 $telefone = $_POST["txttelefone"];
 $senha = $_POST["txtpass"];
 $data = $_POST["txtdata"];


 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysqli_select_db($con,"testeconstrusite");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
     echo "Falha ao conectar ao servidor MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

 if (isset($_POST["nid"]))
{
    $nid = $_POST["nid"];
    mysqli_query($con, "update clientes set nome_cliente ='$nome', email_cliente='$email', telefone_cliente='$telefone', senha_cliente='$senha', data_nasc_cliente=STR_TO_DATE('$data','%d/%m/%Y') where nid = '$nid'");
    //executa a query
}
else
{
    mysqli_query($con, "insert into clientes (nome_cliente, email_cliente, telefone_cliente, senha_cliente, data_nasc_cliente) VALUE('$nome', '$email', '$telefone', '$senha', STR_TO_DATE('$data','%d/%m/%Y'))");
    $id_inserido = mysqli_insert_id($con);
}

 ?>
```

**HTML -> Deve renomear para PHP**

```
<?php


 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysqli_select_db($con,"testeconstrusite");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
     echo "Falha ao conectar ao servidor MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

if (isset($_GET['nid']))
{
    $nid = $_GET['nid'];
    $clienteAtual = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("
    SELECT *,
    FROM clientes
    where nid = $nid")) or die(mysql_error()); 
}

?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
 <head>

     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"  href="estilos/estilo.css" />
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

     <title>Cadastro</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="formulario" class = formulario>
 <form action="cadastrar.php" method="post">

     <input type='number' name="txtid" class='campo' id="nid" hidden="hidden" value="<?php echo($nid); ?>">

     <label>Nome *</label><br>
     <input type='text' name="txtnome" class='campo' id="txtnome"  <?php  echo('value="'.$clienteAtual['nome_cliente'].'"');  ?> required>
     <br>

     <label>E-mail *</label><br>
     <input type="email" class='campo' required="required" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$">
     <br>

     <label>Telefone *<span class="esmaecido"></span> </label><br>
     <script type="text/javascript">$("#txttelefone").mask("(00) 0000-00009");</script>
     <input type="tel" class="campo" name="txttelefone" id="txttelefone" required="required" pattern="\([0-9]{2}\)[\s][0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4,5}" />
     <br>

     <label>Senha *</label><br>
     <input type="password" name="txtpass" class='campo' required="required" id="txtpass">
     <br>

     <label>Data de Nascimento *</label><br>
     <script type="text/javascript">$("#txtdata").mask('00/00/0000');</script>
     <input type='data' name="txtdata" id="txtdata" class='campo' required="required">
     <br>

     <input type='submit' name='BTEnvia' value='Cadastrar' class = botao><br>

 </form>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Já consegui adicionar na primeira pagina o campo id escondido puxando o id quando a pessoa clica no link pra editar @RovannLinhalis agora falta fazer a alteração no cadastro com a condição.

Comment: @ArnaudLanna editei minha resposta com seu código, veja se ajuda

Comment: quando abro o index o seguinte erro é retornado: `( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: nid in C:\wamp64\www\testeb\index.php on line 42 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003241144{main}( )...\index.php:0 "> Nome *`

Comment: Consegui modificar meu código, tá funcionando perfeitamente, só não preenche os campos, como faço isso?

Comment: no código que alterei, os campos de id e nome deveriam ser preenchidos

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar outra pagina de alteração para isso.
pagina_alteracao.php

Só que você passa como parâmetro o id que foi guardado na tabela.

Assim o link para alteração ficaria da seguinte forma.

```
<a href="pagina_alteracao.php?id=id_cliente" Editar </a>
```

Com esse id você pode pegar através da query:

SELECT * FROM cliente where id=id_cliente

Ai so precisa fazer a query para alterar os dados.